# python selenium no such element exception

Tags: python, selenium

Having trouble getting selenium to send keys to username field. I have tried "find_element_by_css_selector" and all the other find elements. Keep getting no such element exception.

This is the code I have so far:

```
import webbrowser
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
webbrowser.open('https://www.kraken.com/en-us/login')
browser.implicitly_wait(10)
browser.find_element_by_name('username').send_keys('your-username')
```

Comment: Are you sure you get `NoSuchElement` with provided piece of code? It seem like this `webbrowser.open('https://www.kraken.com/en-us/login')` should looks like this `browser.get('https://www.kraken.com/en-us/login')`

Comment: To be more pointed, what is `webbrowser`?  You haven't assigned nor imported that name.

Comment: Can you tell me why do you use `webbrowser` variable with method `open`? Is that typo? Your code works fine on my machine if you use `browser.get(http://...)`

Comment: You are opening the browser with  `browser` but navigating with `webbrowser`. `browser` still have blank page, therefor no elements to locate.

Comment: Thanks for the reply's, it works now. I have another question:  How do I open the url in a new tab, instead of a new window.  I'm asking this because for other websites log in's, the username/password elements are only visible when the window in in full screen.

Answer (score 0):

Good Question.This problem is caused because Selenium didn't find the element.TO fix this you need to replace the implicity_wait with 'time.sleep(in seconds)'.This will make selenium wait for the entire website to load.Some elements of the website take more time to load.Implicity wait won't work here.

Comment: How did you find such an old and bad question, which had an answer already (see the comments)? Anyway, I think that suggesting the use of time.sleep() is really a bad approach, you should have looked for [page_loading_strategy](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/page_loading_strategy/) or the use of [expected_conditions](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html?highlight=expected)

Comment: I am a lazy programmer.So,i don't go into such chaos.Anyways thanks for your reply.Nice to meet you